# WPF .g.cs files are not being generated?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

The generated ***window*.g.cs** file for a window I made is not being created. Is there any way where I can manually generate the file?

Comment: Does a stale file exist, or has no file been created at all?

Answer (score 12):

You may have accidentally changed the Build Action of the .xaml file. Select the file in Solution Explorer and ensure the Build Action is set to Page.

Comment: This answer is totally it!  I hope you get an accept, Kent, because this was just what I needed.  Thanks!